# Two function and alert not working?

Tags: jquery

Html Code

```
<body>
<h1 align="center">Are you ready?</h1>
<h2 align="center">Just answer Yes or No!</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button id="ohyes" class="buttonYes"> Yes </button>
    <button id="ohno" class="buttonNo"> No </button>
</div>
</body>
```

Jquery Code

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#ohno").on({
        mouseover: function () {
            $(this).css({
                left: (Math.random() * 800) + "px",
                right: (Math.random() * 800) + "px",
                top: (Math.random() * 400) + "px",
            });
        }

    });

    $("#ohyes").click(function () {
        alert("yes"); //use .val() if you're getting the value
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to call function in jquery first is working fine button is moving on mouseover but when I click the button having id ohyes isn't showing any alert box? 
any suggestions?

Comment: You're probably using Internet Explorer and you get a syntax error due to the trailing `,` in your object.

Comment: If it is dynamically created element, you may want to use .on delegate as you used for the #ohno button

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - sharp eyes. `+1`

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No I'm testing in Mozilla firefox.

Comment: What does the Javascript Console have to say?  Syntax error?

Comment: I think you should maintain the same syntax of associating the event with the elements in your code. `.on()` at some place and `.click()` directly at some place. both work fine, but keep your code clean always.maintain same std.

Comment: Is `ohyes` a dynamically created element???

Comment: @all HTML code added.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario html posted.

Comment: is this the full html? considering that the first is working, the only think that i could think of that might stop that alert is if you have another element with the same id

Answer (score 0):

Try this : this will alert on second button `ohyes` on click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ohno").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({
            left:(Math.random()*800)+"px",
            right:(Math.random()*800)+"px",
            top:(Math.random()*400)+"px",
        });
    });

    $("#ohyes").click(function(){ 
         alert("yes");  //use .val() if you're getting the value
    });  
});
```

Comment: Can you show me your html code ? because i have tried in my local and its working fine so show me your html code.

Comment: @RegisteredUser does jquery is loaded ?

Comment: @DipeshParmar when I'm placing cursor over no it isn't moving means function 1st isn't working man

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ohyes function in a document ready block
either using this
`jQuery(function($){...});`
or this
`$(document).ready(function(){...});`

replace the ellipsis with your ohyes function
As you can see.. your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/willypt/xsyxV/2/